# ActiveAdmin bug? Nested form in show resource page does not display form submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, nested-forms

I am using ActiveAdmin to build an article show page where new comments can be added using a nested form but facing a problem. Article `has_many :comments` and also `accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments`. It all works fine in Rails console but I can't get the form submit button to show up. Here is my code for customizing activeadmin's show page for Article:

```
show do |article|
  attributes_table do
    row :id
    row :title 
  end

  div do
    semantic_form_for [:admin, article], builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f|
      f.has_many :comments, allow_destroy: false, new_record: true, heading: false do |g|
        g.input :body
      end
      f.actions
    end
  end
end
```

The nested form is displayed and works correctly but the submit button is not displayed (meaning that `f.actions` has no effect).

Comment: Any idea ? how did you fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: I moved the Nested form to a view and i'm able to see the "Update" button. like

```
show do
 attributes_table do
  row :id
  row :description
 end
 panel "Link Projects" do
  render partial: 'project_links', locals: { id: company }
 end  
end
```